# Solr analyzer - use file

Tags: solr

I am writing my own analyzer, and i need to use a file with rules in it. I need this file to be configurable in schema. I wrote such code to get this file:

```
String fileName = args.get("file");
File file = new File(fileName);
```

This code gets searches file in directory, where solr.home is. In my case it is "example" directory. But i need to search it in cores conf directory. How can i specify to look it in that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for everyone, who will need such functionality:

1. Implement **ResourceLoader.**
2. Add unimplemented method
   **inform(ResourceLoader).**
3. Get lines from file using method **resourceLoader.getLines(String filePath).** File must be stored in conf directory.
4. Put lines as **local variable**, because inform method is
   called, when solr starts.
5. Pass lines to filter when needed.

That`s all!